# which accuracy is stated in the results/comparison section of machine learning research papers? Is it Training Accuracy or Validate Accuacy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm working on Human Activity Recognition where I'm currently trying to reproduce results of a paper by running a GitHub repository where the paper is being implemented. It almost took me two months to get the code running and now I'm finally able to run the code with following results.

After training the model for about 200 epochs, I get a training accuracy of 80%, where as validation accuracy stagnates at about 50%. In the paper as well as in the repository they have stated accuracy of 83% with the table title as "Mean accuracy (over three splits) on UCF-101". Now I'm really confused that either they are talking about training accuracy or validation accuracy? Because I don't see getting any higher than 50% with my validation accuracy. And I should not alter any parameters in my model as I'm running the code from repository and I should get the mentioned results in the paper and repository?

Base Paper: https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2014/file/00ec53c4682d36f5c4359f4ae7bd7ba1-Paper.pdf.

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/wushidonguc/two-stream-action-recognition-keras